# Why do I get "cannot move out of ... because it is borrowed" although no data is referenced?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

```
struct Population<'a> {
    dat: Vec<Genotype<'a>>,
}

impl<'a> Population<'a> {
    fn new(dat: Vec<Genotype<'a>>) -> Self {
        Population { dat }
    }

    fn select(&self) -> Genotype {
        self.dat.first().unwrap().clone()
    }
}

#[derive(Clone)]
struct Genotype<'a> {
    data: &'a str,
}

impl<'a> Genotype<'a> {
    fn new(data: &'a str) -> Self {
        Genotype { data }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let hello = "Hello World";
    let genotype = Genotype::new(hello);
    let mut population = Population::new(vec![genotype]);

    let other = population.select();
    drop(population);
    println!("{}", other.data);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=abbb8ae9b3b30ace1bae38fda0e7c0fd)

The compiler claims that `population` cannot be dropped because it is borrowed in `other`:

```
error[E0505]: cannot move out of `population` because it is borrowed
  --> src/main.rs:32:10
   |
31 |     let other = population.select();
   |                 ------------------- borrow of `population` occurs here
32 |     drop(population);
   |          ^^^^^^^^^^ move out of `population` occurs here
33 |     println!("{}", other.data);
   |                    ---------- borrow later used here
```

I fail to see how both variables have a relationship with each other. I suspect the error to be in the `select` function as this is apparently the source of the borrow.

I have tried adding a separate lifetime to `select` (`fn select<'b>(&self) -> Genotype<'b>`) but that failed as I think that the compiler assumes that the lifetime of the `Population` instance is somehow linked with the returned `Genotype` even though it relates to the inner `&str`.

What am I doing wrong exactly?

Comment: it's very hard to explain, https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4b5b97ddc85d538dd1ea5fc525b61fb1, best advice don't do this, lifetime is not useful for rust beginner, just don't use reference in your structure. Keep it simple. Use `Rc` if you really need to share thing.

Comment: I have just tried it and the compiler just hints that I should add the anonymous lifetime to the ```select``` function (```fn select(&self) -> Genotype<'_>```) but the error remains the same.

Comment: @Stargateur Thanks for the help, that worked. So basically this just tells the compiler that the lifetime is specifically linked to the inner ```&str``` instead of some anonymous lifetime, is that somewhat correct?

Comment: @Shepmaster Ah I now see what you mean, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I suspect the error to be in the `select` function as this is apparently the source of the borrow.

Yes.

> the compiler assumes that the lifetime of the `Population` instance is somehow linked with the returned `Genotype`

Yes, that's what your code says is the case.

> even though it relates to the inner `&str`

What part of the `select`'s function signature indicates that? Without specifically saying anything, you are relying on [lifetime elision](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-03-lifetime-syntax.html?highlight=elision#lifetime-elision), so your function signature is the same as:

```rust
fn select<'x>(&'x self) -> Genotype<'x>
```

In words, that is: "I'm returning a `Genotype` that contains within it a reference that is guaranteed to be valid as long as `&self` is valid".

Instead, you likely want:

```rust
fn select(&self) -> Genotype<'a>
```

In words, that is: "I'm returning a `Genotype` that contains within it a reference that is guaranteed to be valid as long as the lifetime `'a` is valid".

---

I strongly encourage everyone to add `#![deny(rust_2018_idioms)]` to the root of every crate. That will cause a compiler error for code like `-> Genotype`, prompting the programmer to think about exactly which lifetime is appropriate to place there.

Years of experience has shown that allowing lifetime elision to apply to structs with lifetimes inside of them was a bad choice and this lint helps improve the situation.

Comment: Thanks also for the suggestion of adding the lint. I think I now understand how important this can be.